In AWS Superset: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, when editing scoping of filters
When I try to change the scoping of a  filter in my dahsbaoard or when I try to edit the cross filter, I get the unexpected error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
Other dashboards still work. I already made a new dashboard. It worked in the beginning but suddenly gave the same error.
The error also gives a long list with where the maximum call stack size has exceeded, as shown in the image.
New filters have the same problem.
The error:
    in Ai
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in Sd
    in div
    in F
    in Styled(F)
    in div
    in div
    in D
    in div
    in ForwardRef(j)
    in v
    in ForwardRef
    in c
    in Styled(c)
    in ForwardRef(Qd)
    in ForwardRef(Qd)
    in div
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in Bs
    in form
    in ForwardRef(Pe)
    in o
    in ForwardRef(j)
    in Styled(Component)
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in d
    in div
    in div
    in Unknown
    in Unknown
    in div
    in n
    in CSSMotion
    in Content
    in div
    in div
    in w
    in ForwardRef
    in n
    in Dialog
    in re
    in Unknown
    in Styled(Component)
    in fc
    in yc
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in uu
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in zu
    in yh
    in d
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in d
    in div
    in Styled(div)
    in Jh
    in A
    in Connect(A)
    in le
    in l
    in d
    in Suspense
    in t
    in t
    in b
    in t
    in P
    in y
    in d
    in it
    in Unknown
    in s
    in y
    in ut
    in t
    in t
    in Unknown

The error:
